# How come Ted's daughter and son are in so few episodes?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

I was just looking at *How I Met Your Mother*'s IMDb [cast page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm) and realised that Lyndsy Fonseca and David Henrie, who play daughter and son respectively, are in only 65 episodes, while the show lasted 208 episodes.

If I remember correctly, all episodes begin with Ted telling his kids and almost always starting with "Kids". Am I remembering wrong? I mean, there is a whopping 143 episodes in between. One or two is okay, but 143?

Comment: Why is your question here? No offense intended, but we can't tell you what and how your remember things, and if it's correct or not. Do you mean to know if the IMDb is wrong/missing something? If the math is correct?

Comment: @OldPadawan - The question seems perfectly clear to me. They're referred to repeatedly, but aren't in many episodes. Why not? I'm assuming the answer is that they only pre-filmed a few tens of sequences when they first started out the show.

Comment: "*Fonseca and Henrie filmed all their scenes during the first few seasons of the show, and this stock footage was used throughout the course of the show. The finale was no different—Fonseca and Henrie filmed their parts in the ending secretly.*" If you use stock footage too often, it starts to become quite obvious

Comment: Maybe you should state why you think they should be in more, if any; the show is not about them.  If they never had on-screen time, the show would have worked just as well.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - Which begs the question of why they're in it at all. What was the deciding factor in including the stock footage *in some episodes and not others?*

Comment: It just seemed strange there's a gap of 143 episodes. I mean, one or two is acceptable, but 143?

Comment: You keep saying "a gap of 143 episodes." Were there really 143 in a row without them? (Never watched the show, not a snarky question.) If so, that *would* be weird.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I don't know if in a row, but still...

Comment: @Tolga : is your main point/question is that you think they should be in more episodes? Because they're referred to repeatedly, but aren't in many episodes? And that you would like to know the reason why they weren't? I haven't watched this show, but many shows have "*2nd row*" characters that are important, continuously referred to, but aren't physically present. Think Ms Cooper (14/279), Beverly Hofstadter (16/279) ([TBBT](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/fullcredits/?ref_=ttep_ql_1)) and others...

Comment: @OldPadawan I thought all episodes started with future Ted sitting them down and begin telling them a story. Given that, they should have been in all of the 208 episodes, and yet IMDb cast page for HIMYM says they are in only 65. This is what cofuses me.

Comment: To my recollection, what you are describing only happened toward the end of the series run.  The children were not introduced until the reveal got closer.  The narrative overlay happened frequently.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger would you make that an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Realistic answer is, the show spanned about 9 years, and the actor and the actress grew considerably since their teenage years. So it would create a problem because Ted's storytelling happens during a few days or weeks, but the kids seem to grow in drastic speed.

Therefore, the creators most likely filmed a limited number of scenes when they were young, and did not have much material to show them again and again in later years. Even their scenes in the final episode was filmed years before 2014.

> The final scene with Ted’s teenage kids was filmed eight years ago
> around the start of season 2. This was primarily done because the
> creators knew the two actors playing Ted’s kids would age as the show
> moved forward. (How else did you think Ted’s two teens look ageless
> throughout the nine-season series?)
>
> Of course, this may not be news to die-hard fans of the series. Thomas
> elaborated more on the pre-recorded ending back in 2008 to Zap2It.
>
> “We've had a plan since the pilot and we actually shot a little piece
> of it at the beginning of season two, using the kids, because we knew
> if we waited until the finale of the series, the kids would have aged
> like six years. So yeah, part of our plan for how we want to end it
> all has already been done.”

[Businessinsider Article](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-i-met-your-mother-finale-scene-filmed-years-ago-2014-4)